# Outside of Emacs what other software supports org-mode syntax?

Tags: org-mode

### Context

In my spare time, I've been adding [**very limited support** for org-mode syntax in the Atom text editor](https://atom.io/packages/org-mode) for my friends that absolutely will not switch to Emacs.

Over the last few years I've found approximately 10 org syntax parsers which all focus on converting org-mode files into markdown or other file formats.

The 2 most popular parsers that I use everyday and recommend are:

- [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)
- [org-ruby](https://github.com/wallyqs/org-ruby) gem which provides limited support org-mode syntax for both [Github](https://github.com/github/markup), [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/pages/org-mode).

### Question

Outside of Emacs what other software supports org-mode syntax?

> **Note:** I acknowledge that StackExchange platform is not really ideal for this type of question but I believe the Emacs StackExchange community would benefit from multiple well researched answers about this topic.

### How to Answer this Question

Each answer should:

- Limit answer scope to a single software source, e.g. discuss pandoc or org-ruby but not both in the same answer.
- Briefly describe what software can do with org-mode file, e.g. pandoc can convert org-mode to docx, markdown and json file formats.
- Provide a simple example of using the software, e.g. `pandoc --from org --to docx -o example.docx example.org`.
- List dependencies, e.g. ruby is required to use org-ruby.
- Link to official software page.

### Vote for the most useful answer

Comment: @phils yup! Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: https://opensource.com/article/19/1/productivity-tool-org-mode is highly relevant.

Comment: Visual Studio Code as also an org-mode plug-in, but I did not tested it.

Comment: prolly not what you are looking for but worth mentioning: orgzly (android app) and https://org-web.org/

Comment: org-js https://github.com/mooz/org-js, parser written in JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

#### [Atom org-mode Package](https://atom.io/packages/org-mode)

- The Atom `org-mode` package provides syntax highlighting for org files in the Atom editor.
- Most of the package files are managed from a central [literate programming file](https://github.com/melioratus/org-mode/blob/master/org/atom-org-mode-package.org) and tangled or exported directly from Emacs.
- After the syntax highlighting grammar is completed, a JavaScript org syntax parser will be added to facilitate more comprehensive functionality.
- Use the Atom editor built in package management tool to install the package including the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

#### [org-js](https://github.com/mooz/org-js)

- `org-js` coverts org syntax into html.
- Code Example Quoted from README

  > Simple example of `org -> HTML` conversion
  >
  > ```
  > var org = require("org");
  >
  > var parser = new org.Parser();
  > var orgDocument =   parser.parse(orgCode);
  > var orgHTMLDocument = orgDocument.convert(org.ConverterHTML,   {
  >   headerOffset: 1,
  >   exportFromLineNumber: false,
  >   suppressSubScriptHandling: false,
  >   suppressAutoLink: false
  > });
  >
  > console.dir(orgHTMLDocument); // => { title, contentHTML, tocHTML, toc }
  > console.log(orgHTMLDocument.toString())   // => Rendered HTML
  > ```
- Requires Javascript

  > `npm install org`.

Answer (score 0):

#### [org-ruby](https://github.com/wallyqs/org-ruby)

- `org-ruby` is a ruby gem which converts org syntax into `html`, `textile` and `markdown`.
- The gem is used by Github, Gitlab, and Gollum projects to provide org syntax support for documentation.
- Code Example Quoted from README

  > ```
  > require 'org-ruby'
  >
  > # Renders HTML
  > Orgmode::Parser.new("* Hello world!").to_html
  > # => "<h1>Hello world!</h1>\n"
  >
  > # Renders Textile
  > Orgmode::Parser.new("* Hello world!").to_textile
  > # => "h1. Hello world!\n" 
  >
  > # Renders Markdown
  > Orgmode::Parser.new("* Hello world!").to_markdown
  > # => "# Hello world!\n" 
  >
  > # Renders HTML with custom markup
  > Orgmode::Parser.new("* *Custom* /Markup/", { markup_file: "html.tags.yml" }).to_html
  > # => "<h1><strong>Custom</strong> <em>Markup</em></h1>\n"
  >
  > # Renders Markdown with custom markup
  > Orgmode::Parser.new("* *Custom* /Markup/", { markup_file: "md.tags.yml"}).to_markdown
  > # => "# __Custom__ _Markup_\n"
  > ```
  >
  > The supported output exporters can be also called from the command line:
  >
  > ```
  > org-ruby --translate html         sample.org
  > org-ruby --translate textile      sample.org
  > org-ruby --translate markdown     sample.org
  > org-ruby --markup html.tags.yml   sample.org
  > org-ruby --markup md.tags.yml --translate markdown sample.org
  > ```
- Requires ruby

  > `gem install org-ruby`